# Reduce the number of data points on X axis in highcharts

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, nativescript

I have, with an api call, data coming back for a Highcharts graph, an array of datetimes (in milliseconds) and corresponding values (yAxis). I get data for every 15 minutes. They are rendered on a mobile device.
When I render a monthly view, I get way too much datapoints (4*24*30) to be visualized.
I would only like to visualize 1 datapoint per day, which would be an average of those 4 (quarters) * 24 datapoints.
I tried xAxis options minRange, minTickInterval, tickAmount, tickInterval, ... but they don't do the job.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Highcharts Stock you could achieve that with `dataGrouping`. Highcharts Stock contains all Highcharts features, so if you don't want to use Stock you could just use the Highcharts constructor.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [["day", [1]]]
    }
  }
},
```

**API references:** 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

**Live demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-ydnfmd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I am afraid that without `dataGrouping` the only options will be to filter/parse your data on your own.